# 22.04 Clean Install, what are these partitions?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, 22.04

I have a 5 year old Dell 5820 with two 1TB SSDs. I had been running 18.04 for some time until for some reason my second monitor stopped working. Long story short, I did a fresh install of 22.04 Desktop. Once the install completed I was looking around in the File Manager. File Manager shows devices I do not recognize. I have:
[image]

Devel was a mount point I used to get to the second drive in 18.04, I have no idea where it came from. sda2 I am guessing is the boot partition and sdb1 is the second hard drive. But what is nvme1n1p2? Where did it come from and what do I do with it. Computer seems to be the full root directory and 1.0TBVolume seems to be a partial root directory.

If someone could straighten me out on what is going on I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: What data is lost? The title of your question doesn't seem to relate to the text.

Comment: Your question title and your question body don't match up.  `nvme1n1p2` is a partition on an NVMe disk.

Comment: Yes terrible question. I have changed the tile and changed the question. I created a second question to deal with the missing data. I do not understand where these 4 partitions/drives came from. Nor do I know what one does with a nvme* drive/partition.

Comment: I think you may be misleading yourself and us. You say you did a fresh install. It looks more like to installed over the top of your old installation, hence you have artefacts from the old installation. You appear to have at least 3 storage devices. One is an nvme drive which is an upgrade to a regular SATA SSD. You also seem to have two SATA drives, sda and sdb with an unknown number of partitions. If I were you I would install Ubuntu again but this time make it a truly fresh install. Make backups of any data you cannot afford to lose first. You should probably install to the nvme drive

Comment: Yes, it was a 'fresh' install on top of 18.04. But I *think* I told the installer to reformat and partition the boot drive. Your advice is appreciated, I ended up using Disks and GParted to simple remove any partition that was on the 3-data drives and set each drive up with a single partition each. I then loaded zfs and set all three drives in a pool. So far everything seems fine.